# How to build a multilevel menu from associative array.

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, associative

Please, I need help on this one.
I want to build a multilevel menu, so I want to iterate through an associative array with foreach loop inside smarty template.
First, I have this mysql output:
[image]

Now I try to get an associative array from it, so I tried
`fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`, but because the column names are the same, it gives me values from the right column:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 7 [name] => Beta 1-3 glucan ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 8 [name] => Okinawa Fucoidan )
```

Please if you have any ideas how to process this table to get a multidimentional menu, let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: I assume you `JOIN` tables and in both of them you have `id` and `name` (or you JOIN the same table). What you need to do, is to use `AS` in your query, for example: instead of `SELECT * FROM table JOIN table ON ...` write `SELECT t1.id AS level1_id, t1.name AS level1_name, t2.id AS level2_id, t2.name AS level2_name FROM table t1 JOIN table t2 ...` . This solution will give you 4 different field names in each row (level1_id, level1_name, level2_id, level2_name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use FETCH_NUM or create aliases in the query.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you `JOIN` tables and in both of them you have `id` and `name` (or you JOIN the same table). What you need to do, is to use `AS` in your query.

For example:

Instead of: `SELECT * FROM table JOIN table ON [...]`

Write: `SELECT t1.id AS level1_id, t1.name AS level1_name, t2.id AS level2_id, t2.name AS level2_name FROM table t1 JOIN table t2 ON [...]` .

This solution will give you 4 different field names in each row (`level1_id`, `level1_name`, `level2_id`, `level2_name`).